# How do I stop or fix Outlook.com rendering emoticons as letters?

Tags: outlook.com

In Firefox and Chrome, outlook.com renders smiley faces (☺) as the character `J`.

This is because Firefox and Chrome do not support Wingdings font, which is what outlook.com uses to turn :) into ☺.

Is there any way of fixing this or stopping it happening?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't stop that from happening, at least for now, see reference.

I'm on a Chromebook and wasn't able to find references on the internet about either Chrome OS or Chrome implementing the Unicode version 7.

### Reference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7862643/1536038

Comment: Is there any Firefox extension or bookmarklet that will convert these to Unicode? Any solution whatsoever?